# Do SOCKS proxy servers exist that have SSL support?

Tags: ssl, proxy, socks

I came across an open source SOCKS client library that supports connecting to a SOCKS proxy using a trustmanager key to verify the remote server.

However, I have been unable to find SOCKS proxy servers that support this. Are these available at all commercial or not?

The library in question is [sockslib](https://github.com/fengyouchao/sockslib) (Java), which sports this specific [client example](https://github.com/fengyouchao/sockslib/blob/master/src/test/java/sockslib/example/SSLSocks5Client.java).

A related question: with this specific library, it is possible to define both a keymanager key (in addition to the trustmanager key) as well as normal credentials. Does this make sense for SOCKS servers?

Comment: It is possible for a client to connect to a proxy itself using SSL, if it knows it is connecting to a proxy that expects SSL. But after the connection to the remote server is created, the client is supposed to create any server-side SSL session with the server directly, the proxy is just a pass-through. I don't see how it makes sense for the proxy to verify the server when the server doesn't know what kind of client has connected to it, the server cannot perform a double-handshake. Unless the proxy is sniffing any SSL handshake that the client and server may exchange with each other...

Comment: ... but that is not the proxy's responsibility, the client is expected to verify the identity of the server, and vice versa, as needed.

Comment: There is no thing as a TrustManager key.

Comment: @EJP I checked and TrustManagers are a Java mechanism for managing X.509 public key certificates, to confirm a server's identity.

Comment: "...using a trustmanager key to verify the remote server." - from a short look at the source code of the library: it is only verifying the connection to the proxy, not to the remote server. Which makes sense because a socks proxy just creates a layer 4 tunnel and is not even aware of the protocol spoken inside the tunnel. This mean that it also does not know if TLS is used or not.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Exactly, but I can't find a proxy server that supports this.

Answer (score 3):

[WinGate](http://www.wingate.com) SOCKS server supports accepting a connection (TCP) and immediately performing a TLS handshake on it prior to SOCKS protocol.

It also supports authenticating to the SOCKS server using client certificates.  Or you can just do plaintext (or even GSS-API) auth after that.

Note that this is NOT the method proposed in draft-aft-socks-ssl-00 in 1997 which proposed layering TLS over the top of SOCKS framing (IMO an unnecessarily complicated way of doing it, which only provides a single benefit - being able to negotiate SSL or not - with a lot of down-sides).